# What is the best way to use HTTP Keep-Alive in Python 2.7

Tags: python, http, urllib2, keep-alive

There are several options to use Keep-Alive.
I'm trying to use urllib2 to use Keep-Alive, but it doesn't officially support it in Python 2.7.
I heard pycurl had the funciton. That's why I'm here to ask.

Could you kindly tell me what is the best practice to use Keep-Alive in Python?

**EDIT**

Some said this question had been already asked, but I suppose many people are confused about what module they should to use for Keep-Alive. This is NOT talking about urllib2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. It has [Keep-Alive](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) support in addition to many other features.